# Access other slice of state in reducer using @ngrx/store

Tags: redux, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store-4.0

Given the following (and assuming we cannot change the state's structure):

```
StoreModule.forRoot({
  a: aReducer,
  b: {
        b1: b1Reducer,
        b2: b2Reducer
     }
});
```

and `b1Reducer` is dependent on the value of `a` (for example because it contains something like user info). 
What is the most idiomatic way to access (read-only) `a` in `b1Reducer`?

The solution I came up with is using `@ngrx/effects`, dispatch another action with `a` that can be used in the reducer:

```
@Effect()
augmentAction$ = this.action$
    .ofType(Actions.Action1)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store$)
    .switchMap(([action, state]:[Action, AppState]) => {
        const a = state.a;
        return [new Actions.Action2(a)];
    });
```

This works, but it becomes hard to manage if almost every action needs to be redispatched if `a` is used in many reducers. Is there a better way to handle this?